# how to add slash after removing html extension

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, slash

how to add / at the end using following code after removing html extension:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
DirectorySlash off

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}/ -d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [QSA,L]
```

Comment: i can't help you, but you should be more specific: you should say you're having problems with apache and mod rewrite (it's just a guess, but you should have told it in first place) and also add the correct tags (somethink like html,apache,mod-rewrite,file extension should do) to help people help you out... just an advice

Comment: Thanks for reply the above code changes following url http://www.example.co.uk/page.html to http://www.example.co.uk/page , what i need is / at the end after page to get http://www.example.co.uk/page/

Comment: Please tag your question appropriately; 'html', and more-so the others, are entirely irrelevant to your question.

Comment: i meant you should be more specific when you say what you're talking about, and not what you actually need. a proper tagging (as David Thomas pointed out) can help apache-experts to retrieve your post and help you. i just know that mod_rewrite for apache can do what you need, but i don't know how. others may do, but without a proper tagging and a proper explicit question, you risk nobody reads this.

Comment: is it good now? I don't have problems, I only need slash at the end of my url

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make some changes.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On    
RewriteBase /

#Code to add forward slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(?:\.\w+|/)$
RewriteRule (.*) $1/ [R,L]

#To check whether a .html appended string is a file existing on the system 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1.html [L]

#### NOT REQUIRED
#RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}/ -d
#RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html !-f
#RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R,L]
```

Also these rules will not work as desired:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule [^/]+/$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [QSA,L]
```

cos, `%{REQUEST_URI}` will always have `/` at the end. If a URI like `domain.com/about` is requested for,

It will be rewritten to:

```
domain.com/about/
```

and finally to

```
domain.com/about/.html
```